# If 2 seperate radio inputs are selected. Do something

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get apply both radio choices the user inputs and great a jquery statement around it.
The first statement works where bg == navy blue.

How can I combine the else if statement if bg is = both green and navy blue?

```js
function CB(bg) {
  var url;

  if (bg == "Navy Blue") {
    url = "myurl1";
    document.getElementById("showpicture").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
  } else if (bg == "Navy Blue" && bg == "Green") {
    url = "myurl2";
    document.getElementById("showpicture").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Color</h3>
<label>
  <input id="background-choice" type="radio" name="color" value="Navy Blue"
    onClick="CB(this.value);" />
  <img src="https://www.colorhexa.com/000080.png">
</label>
<h3>Pattern</h3>
<label>
  <input id="background-choice" type="radio" name="pattern" value="Green"
    onClick="CB(this.value);" />
  <img src="https://www.colorhexa.com/024e49.png">
</label>
```

Comment: your second condition never gonna satisfy. how can `bg` be both green and navy blue at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean something like this  - otherwise why use radios in the first place

Using your code: https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/ExyjeLv

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type === "radio") {
    const colorRad = this.querySelector("[name=color]:checked")
    const patternRad = this.querySelector("[name=pattern]:checked")
    const color = colorRad ? colorRad.value : "default"
    const pattern = patternRad ? patternRad.value : "default"

    let url = "default.png";
    if (color === "Navy Blue" && pattern === "default") {
      url = "myUrl1.png";
    } else if (color === "Navy Blue" && pattern === "Green") {
      url = "myurl2.png";
    }
    const urlString = "url(" + url + ")";
    console.log(urlString)
    document.getElementById("showpicture").style.backgroundImage = urlString
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h3>Color</h3>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Navy Blue"/>
  <img src="https://www.colorhexa.com/000080.png">
</label>
  <h3>Pattern</h3>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="pattern" value="Green"/>
  <img src="https://www.colorhexa.com/024e49.png">
</label>
</div>

<div id="showpicture"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @mplungjan Cant seem to get it to work, https://codepen.io/Justanewbielearning/pen/VwjLGMd

Comment: Several reasons. 1. I use ID you use CLASS on the container 2. You have special characters in your name. 3. you have the same URL in if and in else. Have a look here: https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/ExyjeLv